# App crash on allowing permission for the notification in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

When application is launched for the first time after download. It asks for different permissions. After granting permissions app closes. You have to launch the app again to continue. I have used Location service, Push Notifications. The issue in there only in ios 7.

EDIT:
Here is the console log

```
    Sep 12 17:54:51  medialibraryd[3640] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} [MediaLibraryService] Cancelling any active or suspended import operations in progress for process assistant_servic (process ID = 3708)
    Sep 12 17:54:51  medialibraryd[3640] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} [MLWriter] Cleaning up any remaining transactions for ended process <unknown process> (process ID = 3708)
    Sep 12 17:54:55  backboardd[28] <Warning>: com.SoundViewTech.EliteLive failed to launch in time
    Sep 12 17:54:55  backboardd[28] <Warning>: Forcing crash report of Elite[3711]...
    Sep 12 17:54:55  backboardd[28] <Warning>: Finished crash reporting.
    Sep 12 17:54:55  com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.SoundViewTech.EliteLive[0x9536]) Exited: Killed: 9
    Sep 12 17:54:55  backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.SoundViewTech.EliteLive[0x9536]' exited abnormally with signal 9:

 Killed: 9
```

Thanks

Comment: You will need to supply, debug console output, crash logs and code. There is no way we can tell what is going on without out does.

Comment: That isn't a crash log.  It's a console log that says it has **created** a crash log.  OTOH, "failed to launch in time" is a clue...you're probably blocking the main thread during launch.

Comment: @PhillipMills I amnot doing any thing on main thread

Comment: Then please add the real (symbolicated) crash log to your question so we can see what's happening when it fails.

Comment: @PhillipMills Please download from https://www.dropbox.com/s/9u5sagkg4n3f4tj/Elite%20%2012-09-14%205-54%20pm.crash?dl=0

Comment: That doesn't have the symbols resolved.  Look for instructions on using "symbolicatecrash" and see if the results give you better information.  If you look at what you uploaded, though, you can see methods from "Elite" active on the main thread.  Getting symbols for those should help.